# PostgreSQL Optimal SELECT query with many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, query-optimization

I am using PostgreSQL database and have 4 tables to work with: **registry, invoice, invoice_position, user_involved**

Table registry columns:

```
id
reg_name
```

Table invoice:

```
id
reg_id(FK to registry, can be many invoices in one registry)
invoice_name
```

Table invoice_position:

```
id
invoice_id(FK to invoice, can be many positions in invoice)
position_name
```

Table user_involved:

```
id
Inv_position_id(FK to invoice_position, it's a one to one relationship)
user_name
```

I need to create a SELECT query that would find IF there's more than one occurrence of **user_involved** in the **registry** table (which is only related with user_involved by FK's of invoice_position->invoice->registry). Few things to note, that those tables contain more than +/- 1.000.000 rows each (EXCEPT registry table) and I can't at this point add direct relation between registry and user_involved. The question is how to write an optimal SELECT or if it's even possible at this state, cause nesting multiple SELECTs is going to take forever.

EDIT:
This is what I've tried so far :

```
SELECT rg.id, COUNT(ui.id) FROM registry rg
  LEFT JOIN invoice inv ON inv.reg_id = rg.id
  LEFT JOIN invoice_position ip ON ip.invoice_id = inv.id
  LEFT JOIN user_involved ui ON ui.inv_position_id = ip.id
WHERE ip.id = $id GROUP BY rg.id,ui.id HAVING COUNT (ui.id) > 1;
```

This query will be inside a **while** loop with variable "id" given different invoice position id's.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the queries that you have attempted.

Comment: `user_involved` is related 1:1 with `invoice_position`? super. Ditch `user_involved`, because repetition of a `invoice_position` row implies repetition of a `user_involved` row (right?) Look to ditch `registry` too, because all you want is the `reg_id`, and that's in `invoice`.. so your query can probably be answered with a join on just the 2 tables of `invoice` and `invoice_position` based on what you've claimed (?)

Comment: I assumed the `id` columns are `PRIMARY KEY`s and will therefore already have indexes on them.  could you also update the question with any indexes that exist on the involved tables.  `\d $table` output from `psql` would be great!

Comment: Please act on [mcve]. That includes a clear description of what the output is as a function of input. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Comment: There's no reason to expect "nesting multiple SELECTs is going to take forever". Queries specify results, not algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by doing:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT rg.id, COUNT(ui.id)
FROM invoice_position ip, invoice inv, registry rg, user_involved ui
WHERE ip.id = $id
  AND ip.invoice_id = inv.id
  AND inv.reg_id = rg.id
  AND ui.inv_position_id = ip.id
GROUP BY rg.id
HAVING COUNT(ui.id) > 1;
```

and seeing what you get back.  the reason for not using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s as you were doing is that they limit the plans the optimizer can choose between (or at least they did the last time I checked) and this query doesn't seem to need them.

further to that, you could think about getting several `invoice_position` rows at a time and matching things up outside the database.  that way you can spread the cost of doing a query out a bit, the trade off being a bit more complexity in the calling code.

for example, something like:

```
SELECT ip.id, rg.id, COUNT(ui.id)
FROM invoice_position ip, invoice inv, registry rg, user_involved ui
WHERE ip.id IN $id_list
  AND ip.invoice_id = inv.id
  AND inv.reg_id = rg.id
  AND ui.inv_position_id = ip.id
GROUP BY ip.id, rg.id
HAVING COUNT(ui.id) > 1;
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Please use modern `JOIN` syntax. 2) Even if the OP is typing `LEFT JOIN` the joins end up being inner joins because the way the filtering condition is phrased.

Comment: @TheImpaler using explicit `JOIN` syntax always used to be a good way to limit the query planner; did that get changed and I didn't notice?

Comment: In postgresql `explicit` and `implicit` see as same semantic.. Postgresql is typically free to rearrange the order of join operations and apply `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions in any order it sees fit.

Comment: @dwir182 I'm aware that `INNER` joins have the same semantics in SQL as implicit joins.  however a few years ago (sorry, not sure which version) PG's optimiser used to treat them differently.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-joins.html suggests that, with default settings, there's little difference now but I'm not sure if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

One of the key aspects of your query is the presence of a filtering condition. In the absence of it, there's no other option than to read the whole tables. You don't want to do that, of course.

An alternative that is always worth mentioning is to create/use/maintain materialized views. But that's different topic I don't cover here, since it requires a lot more work. I would consider this one, an option of last resort only, I guess.

Anyway, your query DOES HAVE a filtering condition, albeit only one, that it's an equality (this is kind of great).

PostgreSQL can take great advantage of this filter if:

- The selectivity of the filter is good. That is, the condition `ip.id = $i` select 5% or less of the table rows. Ideally I would put this limit at "less than 0.5%" to make it really fast.
- There's an index on the column used to filter. That is, the table has an index that starts with the column `id`. Maybe an index with that column only. For example:

  ```
  create index ix1 on invoice_position (id);
  ```

If you confirm these conditions are met, please post the execution plan of your query. You can do it by prepending the clause `EXPLAIN` to your query. It won't actually execute the query but will just display the plan you need to post in your question. I can read it, and give you my assessment.

By the way, what's the selectivity of your filtering condition?